# Do "sky" pokeballs have any other use other than catching flying pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-legends-arceus

The "sky" pokeballs (feather/wing/jet) seems to only work on pokemon you see in the field that are flying in the air. Throwing them at pokemon on land or in sea does nothing and it just bounces off of whatever you throw it at.

I have tons of Sky Tumblestones and crafted a bunch hoping I could use it like any pokeball but I can't find any other uses.

**Is there anything else I can do with these pokeballs?**

I'll probably sell most of them off if there's no other point in keeping them. I barely see any flying pokemon anyway.

Comment: I suppose I could probably use them in battle on any pokemon, kinda like the "heavy" balls. [But will probably have no added benefit in a similar manner.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/395269/8995)

Comment: Just did a check, you can use sky balls in battle on any pokemon like any other pokeball.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While the Feather Ball and its variants are primarily used for catching agile or flying Pokemon, they can also be used to catch any type of Pokemon and (literally) snipe catch them from a distance. I used one the other day to catch an Alpha Toxicroak that was surrounded by its minions and couldn't get close.

According to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/PokemonLegendsArceus/comments/sg9hwu/why_do_my_pokeballs_keep_bouncing_off_pokemon/) Reddit thread, each pokeball type seem to have a maximum range they can be used. If the range is exceed, the ball will simply bounce off the target. Additionally, according to [GameRant](https://gamerant.com/pokemon-legends-arceus-flying-gyarados-obsidian-fieldlands-falls/), the Feather Ball and its variants seem to only work if you hit the Pokemon in certain places. In their article, they state

> Feather Balls will simply bounce off of the Pokemon if they hit it on its underside

So perhaps when you threw the Feather Ball, it hit a spot that wasn't registering it as a capture.

Comment: Oh, weird. I've only ever really tried to throw it when relatively close to pokemon. Tried to count on the straight trajectory they usually take on some uneven terrain. Looks like you need to aim lower than normal since the balls travel just above where you aim. The ball itself still has to hit center of mass.

Comment: Seems to be a little more complicated than that, it's really fickle. Sometimes it works, but a lot of times it doesn't.

Comment: "If the range is exceed, the ball will simply bounce off the target" can confirm this, I figured it out throwing Pokeball at a Magikarp swimming too far from the shore...

Comment: After fine tuning my aim with the sky balls, I'm getting much more success using these now. Key is to aim your crosshairs just lower than where you want it to land. I think why it was failing for me was that I aimed at center of mass and it technically hits the pokemon's head which has a smaller "catch" collision (?) box.